# Read_csv when you only know partial filename

Tags: python, pandas

I'm not able to read a csv file for which I know only the partial filename. Here is what I did but I get an error:

> "pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data." 
>   What should I add/change to the code?

```
for f in glob('Name*.csv'):
   df1 = pd.read_csv(f)
```

Comment: What partial information do you have about the name?

Comment: try `os.listdir` then filter name startswith `Name`, then use `read_csv` with filtered file_name

Comment: The files looks like this: Name_hr_date&time (Name_hr_20190619) and so on..

Comment: There is always just one file with that name, so i don't need to worry if we have Name_hr_20190619 and Name_hr_20190618 for example. I just don't want to change the code everytime.

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
files = os.listdir('directory')
filtered_files = [file_  for file_ in files if file_.startswith('Name_hr_')]
df1 = pd.read_csv('directory'+'/'+'filtered_files[0])
```

Explanation:

`os.listdir()` returns all the files in the directory, just filter file which starts with `Name_hr_` and now you have a full_name of the file.

just read_csv with propername :)

**Note:** Incase if you don't have a file with required format, you will get IndexError, to avoid this use try catch block.

Comment: files = os.listdir('C:\\Script')
filtered_files = [file_.startswith('Name_hr_') for file_ in files]
df1 = pd.read_csv(filtered_files[0])

Comment: ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'bool'>. The path is valid...i dont understand.

Comment: can you tell me where exactly your file is placed ? and where you got the error?

Comment: The file is in the "script" folder.

Comment: File ".\test.py",line10,in <module>
 df1 = pd.read_csv(filtered_files[0])
 File "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 702, in parser_f
 return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
File "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 413, in _read
filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression)
File "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 232, in get_filepath_or_buffer
 ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'bool'>

Comment: I think you have some problem with `os.listdir`, can you print result of the `os.listdir()`

Comment: PS C:\\SCRIPT> py .\test.py, and the result is:
['Name_hr_20191906', 'test.py']

Comment: @bogdann - I hope my my updated solution works for you. If you have any difficulty please feel free to raise a question, else accept my answer by clicking grey button at my answer :)